# Heroku Application Error when deploying Dash app

Tags: python, heroku, web-applications, plotly-dash

I am attempting to deploy a web app on Heroku with the app made with Dash. I have successfully deployed several example apps on Heroku, and I have successfully deployed my app on my local server. The problem arises when I try to deploy my own app on Heroku. I have tried several different approaches to deploying on Heroku, but I continue getting “Application Error” despite a successful build. I have included my logs, but could use help understanding them. I am still quite new to this so any insight would be appreciated.

```
2018-06-14T06:16:06.479983+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2018-06-14T06:16:06.479989+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2018-06-14T06:16:06.480336+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2018-06-14T06:16:06.480369+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2018-06-14T06:16:06.571040+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2018-06-14T06:16:06.555492+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-06-14T06:20:34.738228+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=builddlrapp.herokuapp.com request_id=75e9c068-72cb-41e3-8bbd-c6790c722f8e fwd="137.158.71.91" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-06-14T06:20:38.238293+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=builddlrapp.herokuapp.com request_id=c0905560-3e86-4059-918a-3c795824325c fwd="137.158.71.91" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-06-14T06:31:25.832995+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=builddlrapp.herokuapp.com request_id=3d771909-ec4e-4312-9567-6653b443ef6f fwd="137.158.71.91" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-06-14T06:31:26.464840+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=builddlrapp.herokuapp.com request_id=b1ae29be-3f08-4d94-b669-243b5a303a5b fwd="137.158.71.91" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-06-14T06:34:44.629354+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-06-14T06:34:53.953676+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:server`
2018-06-14T06:34:55.963096+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-06-14 06:34:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.8.1
2018-06-14T06:34:55.963587+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-06-14 06:34:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:41360 (4)
2018-06-14T06:34:55.963682+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-06-14 06:34:55 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2018-06-14T06:34:55.967329+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-06-14 06:34:55 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2018-06-14T06:34:56.010075+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-06-14 06:34:56 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2018-06-14T06:34:56.449927+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353527+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-06-14 06:34:57 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353564+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353566+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353567+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353568+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353569+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353570+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353571+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353573+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353574+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353576+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353577+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353578+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353579+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353580+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353581+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353582+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 12, in <module>
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353583+00:00 app[web.1]:     import dash_table_experiments as dt
2018-06-14T06:34:57.353590+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash_table_experiments'
2018-06-14T06:34:57.355356+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-06-14 06:34:57 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358463+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-06-14 06:34:57 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358465+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358466+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358467+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358468+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358469+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358471+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358472+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358473+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358474+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358475+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358476+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358477+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358479+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358480+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358481+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358482+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 12, in <module>
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358483+00:00 app[web.1]:     import dash_table_experiments as dt
2018-06-14T06:34:57.358487+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash_table_experiments'
2018-06-14T06:34:57.360264+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-06-14 06:34:57 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2018-06-14T06:34:57.415375+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-06-14T06:34:57.415384+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 210, in run
2018-06-14T06:34:57.415674+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.sleep()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.415677+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 360, in sleep
2018-06-14T06:34:57.415899+00:00 app[web.1]:     ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2018-06-14T06:34:57.415901+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416091+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416095+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416352+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416387+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416389+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416390+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416391+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416394+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416395+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416514+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416516+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 61, in run
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416632+00:00 app[web.1]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416633+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 223, in run
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416796+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(Application, self).run()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416797+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416923+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.416924+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 232, in run
2018-06-14T06:34:57.417088+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2018-06-14T06:34:57.417089+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 345, in halt
2018-06-14T06:34:57.417316+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.stop()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.417341+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2018-06-14T06:34:57.417542+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1)
2018-06-14T06:34:57.417543+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
2018-06-14T06:34:57.417703+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2018-06-14T06:34:57.417705+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2018-06-14T06:34:57.417949+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2018-06-14T06:34:57.417969+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2018-06-14T06:34:57.482436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-06-14T06:34:57.498547+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: No experience with dash but I guess "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dash_table_experiments'" is the key problem. For some reason it does not load. Are you sure it is installed?

Comment: dash_table_experiments is imported in the actual code. I originally did not pip install dash_table_experiments when using the virtualenv but I have since gone back and installed it, but still no luck.

Comment: import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table_experiments as dt
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output#, State

import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as offline
offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import base64

import features
from support import appProfiles

Comment: These are all my dependencies. After activating virtualenv, I pip install the first four as well as dash-renderer, plotly, and gunicorn. My most recent deployment attempt still gave me an application error. Do I need to pip install any of those other dependencies?

Comment: Sorry for beeing a little slow to answere bur I've never used dash so I'm not really the right guy. I've only worked with Django and then I have a Piplock file that needs to keep all libraries that is needed for my django service. If i forget to add to that file after a pip install the webapp fails.

Answer (score 1):

I included a requirements.txt file with all the packages I needed for the app and pushed to heroku using git via the command line and got it to work. That being said, it's hard to tell what's going on after you have installed the packages via pip in your virtual env. Do the packages still not load?

Here's what I have in my requirements.txt file using the miniconda environment. It might be an more than what you need for your app:

```
cement==2.8.2
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
colorama==0.3.9
Cython==0.28.3
dash==0.21.1
dash-auth==1.0.2
dash-core-components==0.25.1
dash-html-components==0.11.0
dash-renderer==0.13.0
dash-table-experiments==0.6.0
decorator==4.3.0
docutils==0.14
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Compress==1.4.0
Flask-SeaSurf==0.2.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.7
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
jmespath==0.9.3
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
MarkupSafe==1.0
nbformat==4.4.0
numpy==1.14.5
pandas==0.23.3
pathspec==0.5.5
plotly==3.0.2
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.5
PyYAML==3.13
requests==2.19.1
retrying==1.3.3
semantic-version==2.5.0
six==1.11.0
tabulate==0.7.5
termcolor==1.1.0
traitlets==4.3.2
urllib3==1.23
Werkzeug==0.14.1
wincertstore==0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

missing 'dash_table_experiments'
you need to add it to your requirements.txt
git add A-
git commit -m 'modifications'

Answer (score 0):

After installing the missing modules. You need to recreate the requirements.txt file with:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then commit the new changes and deploy. Do so with any other missing modules

Answer (score 0):

You should create a runtime.txt file and indicate the Python you’ve used in installing those dependencies. This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).